# MYSQL find how different two text fields are?

Tags: php, mysql, string, email, text

I'm storing the HTML content of emails in my database.

If I store two of the same emails in my database, that are only a little different because of personalization (one might say "Hello Stephen, thank you for subscribing...", and the other "Hello Andrew, thank you for subscribing...").

How can I tell that these text fields are only slightly different? (maybe get a percentage saying they're 95% alike).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a good starting point for MySQL:
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

A Levenshtein distance is the number of edits required to turn one string into another. You could probably mess with dividing that distance by the length of the string to get a percentage of sorts.

For PHP, there is a builtin Levenshtein function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: Oh snap, this is clever. I'll mark this as correct as soon as I get it to work. ;)

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar Sorry, I was looking at the fact that you're using MySQL. If you want to do this in PHP instead of MySQL, there's a builtin levenshtein function in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: Np. I'd rather do it in MYSQL for performance reasons. Why does the levenshtein function have a 255 character limit on both strings though?

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar I'd imagine that was probably arbitrary (and cause when you get into bigger strings, it's gonna get slower). You can probably change those to `VARCHAR(1024)` for example, although make sure to change the `VARBINARY(256)` inside the procedure to `VARBINARY(1025)` to match. Update the helper function as well, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This could also help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php . 
similar_text() returns the number of matching chars in both strings.

Comment: I think the performance on this one is a lot better than the levenshtein algorithm when comparing long strings.

Comment: According to the PHP manual, levenshtein is quicker than similar_text. levenshtein is O(m*n) (m is len of string 1, n is len of string 2) whereas similar_text is O(n**3) (n is len of longest string).

Comment: Too bad levenshtein doesn't work if "one of the argument strings is longer than the limit of 255 characters." /: