# How to say if two articles about the same incident from different sources are the same using AI?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, string-parsing, semantic-analysis

How can I say if two articles about the same incident but different grammatically and logically are same or different.

Example:

**Case 1**:

- article 1 (news source 1): US trade deficit goes up this fiscal
- article 2 (news source 2): US trade deficit on the rise

result: Both are the same

**Case 2**:

- Article 1 (news source 1): Harvard has younger students this year.
- Article 2 (news source 2): Harvard's entrance gets tougher for students this year.

result: They are different.

Not word to word matching but as a whole. If we can do meaning comparison it is even better.
Which AI concepts do I use and if anyone can share some info about the same would be helpful. I was told Natural Language Processing might help. Please help!!

PS: Please tell me if there is some open source API for the same.

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540315/mysql-find-how-different-two-text-fields-are

Answer (score 1):

To start, have a look at [the Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).
This can help you to create a measure on how 'different' two strings (or texts) are.

For higher level comparisons you need to take into account the semantics indeed. I think WordNet gives acces to semantics of words, which can help you to compare words. [see example](http://opensource.ebswift.com/WordNet.Net/)

Comment: Thanks...I think WordNet serves my purpose..Is there any other API similar to this?